# Android convert color int to hexa String

Tags: android, colors

```
public static int RGB(float[] hsv) {
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

this function add an int, froma  color. how can i convert that int to a hexa string: #efefef

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a color integer to a hex String in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The answer of st0le is not correct with respect to colors. It does not work if first color components are 0. So toHexString is useless.

However this code will work as expected:

```
String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & intColor);
```

Comment: Your absolutely right. I don't understand why the others downvoted your answer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I got a different answer. My R=71, G=159, and B=83 the Hex it's displaying is `6C94C` but it really is `479f53`

Comment: Warning: this 6 digits version would not work with 8 digits hexa colors if using alpha channel.

Comment: For the 8 digits color: String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFFFF & intColor);

Comment: FYI: this answer doesn't support alpha channel.

Answer (score 22):

Here are 2 ways to convert Integer to Hex Strings...

```
    int  n = 123456;
    System.out.println(String.format("#%X", n)); //use lower case x for lowercase hex
    System.out.println("#"+Integer.toHexString(n));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to javascript format:

```
val hexColor = String.format("%06X", 0xFFFFFFFF.and(R.color.text.toColorInt(context).toLong()))

val javascriptHexColor = "#" + hexColor.substring(2) + hexColor.substring(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

**Java:**

```
 String hexColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorTest))
```

**Kotlin:**

```
var hexColor = "#${Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorTest))}"
```